# How do mechanisms of acidic cleavage of ethers differ for anhydrous, concentrated, and aqueous HI?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, ethers

I have seen the usage of anhydrous, concentrated, and aqueous HI for the acidic cleavage of ethers. What is the difference in the mechanisms and which will follow either of S<sub>N</sub>1/S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism?

Once the the oxygen is protonated, which cases would favor a carbocation formation (hence putting the iodide at a bulky site), and when the reaction follows S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism as the leaving group is good (hence putting the iodide at a less bulky site)?

Comment: The stability of the carbocation in the different cases is going to make a significant contribution to which mechanism is followed. If it is a stable cation then SN1 can be followed more easily

Comment: Thank you.Actually the question that had come had an ether having ethyl and tert butyl groups on it . When treated with ANHYDROUS HI the shown product was ethyl iodide and tert butanol(SN2?) ,While I expected tert butyl iodide(SN1) as the product. The first part of my question actually asks about the reagent HI as well

Comment: I am unconvinced by the answer you have been given and a quick Google search reveals a number of sites that agree with you that tBu-I + EtOH are the outcome. There are also sites that give tBuOH + EtI as product. In real life I suspect you would get a mixture. There is also the possibility that if excess HI (as is likely) is present then it will convert the tBuOH to tBu-I

Comment: This looks like a a good summary https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/11/19/ether-cleavage/